# AX2012 Dynamic Dialog Lookup With Two Columns

Tags: dialog, axapta, x++

Has anyone ever created a dynamic dialog formstringcontrol with a lookup that contains two columns?  Something like  VALUE - DETAILS where Value is returned to the field upon selection.

For me, this generally works, except the second (details) column always comes back as Unretrieved.

```
Query                   query = new Query();
QueryBuildDataSource    datasource;
QueryFilter             qFilter;
SysTableLookup sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(MyTable), _control);
sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(MyTable, Field1));
sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(MyTable, Field2));
datasource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(MyTable));
datasource.addGroupByField(fieldNum(MyTable, Field1));
datasource.addOrderByField(fieldNum(MyTable, Field1));
    qFilter = query.addQueryFilter(datasource,'Field3');
    qFilter.value('FilterValue');
}

sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
```

[image: Second field unretrieved]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question correctly, but https://ztirom.at/2015/12/ax2012-dialog-custom-lookup/ seems to do what you are asking.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.. and surprisingly easy. Thanks!

Comment: To help others find this more easily, you could write an answer based on that link and your own solution.

Comment: Will do, once it works.  : )  Ran into a bit of a snag.  Will update the primary question so we have a complete thread.

Comment: Just a note, I see two duplicate `datasource.addOrderByField(fieldNum(MyTable, Field1));` lines. Sometimes `Unretrieved` is resolved by an AOS restart. The reasons for it are longer than the comment will allow.

Comment: I think the "duplicate" was a group by statement, not a second order by.  Restarting didn't fix, but you inadvertently let me to the answer.  Will post on the thread separately.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This ended up being very simple.

The second field was not included in the group by values, but was a string, and thus could not be aggregated.  Therefore it was unretrieved.

In this case, I was just able to remove the Group By attribute, but I suspect grouping by both would have fixed it as well.